# constructing a right adjoint to i:eff C ---> mod C

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, abelian-categories, adjoint-functors, functors

In "[Deriving Auslander's Formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7051.pdf) (Theorem 2.2)", I'm trying to construct a right adjoint to inclusion functor $\mathsf{i:eff~C \to mod~C}$. I constructed it as follows:

> The functor $\mathsf{j:mod~C \to eff~C}$ (right adjoint of $\mathsf{i}$) sends each object $f$ to itself if $f$ is in $\mathsf{eff~C}$, and otherwise it sends $f$ $($with presentation $(-,A) \to (-,B) \to f \to 0$$)$ to $\mathsf{coker}((-,B) \to (-,coker(A \to B)))$.

Now, my problem is: "If $Hom_{\mathsf{C}}(c,-)$ is exact, the latter assignment (above) sends each object to zero object in $\mathsf{eff~C}$. In this case, zero object in $\mathsf{eff~C}$ has many presentations." Is abelianness of $\mathsf{C}$ sufficient for $Hom_{\mathsf{C}}(c,-)$ to be exact? If yes, how can I resolve this difficulty?

**Notes and definitions:**  
$\mathsf{C}$: an abelian category  
$\mathsf{(C^{op},Ab)}$: the category of functors from $\mathsf{C^{op}}$ to $\mathsf{Ab}$ 
**Finitely presented object**: An object $F$ in $\mathsf{(C^{op},Ab)}$ is called **finitely presented** if it has an exact presentation $(-,A) \to (-,B) \to F \to 0$  
$\mathsf{mod~C}$ : the full subcategory of $\mathsf{(C^{op},Ab)}$ consisting of finitely presented objects  
$\mathsf{eff~C}$: the full subcategory of $\mathsf{mod~C}$ consisting of objects $F$ (in definition of "finitely presented object") with $A \to B$ an epimorphism in $\mathsf{C}$

Comment: What difficulty are you referring to? Also, $\hom_C(c, -) : C^{op} \to Ab$ generally isn't exact; presumably the quoted passage (which I can't find in your link) is only meant to apply when it is.

Comment: @Hurkyl The quoted passage is my problem (it's mine) and it's not in the paper. If Hom_C(c, -) : C^{op} ---> Ab is exaxt, Obj(eff C) is just zero object of mod C. In this case, I think zero object has many (non isomorphic) presentations.

Comment: The zero object has many nonisomorphic presentations regardless; e.g. $(-, A) \to (-, A) \to 0 \to 0$ is a presentation of zero for *every* object $A$, or more generally $(-, A) \to (-, B) \to 0 \to 0$ whenever $A \to B$ is a split epimorphism. I still don't understand what you refer to by "the difficulty"; the vibe I get from your writing is that you think what you have written has an obvious consequence that is an (apparent) obstacle or paradox or contradiction... but I can't figure out what obvious consequence you have in mind.

Comment: @Hurkyl You mean that having different (non isomorphic) presentations is not a problem?

Comment: Not in of itself; that's the usual and expected state of affairs.